# MySQL Select Performance on nearly identical tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that contain essentially the same information.

```
  `netid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `host` text,
  `appid` text,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  KEY `cc_search` (`cc`,`dt`),
  KEY `ip_search` (`ip`,`dt`),
  KEY `netid_search` (`netid`,`dt`),
  KEY `dt` (`dt`),
  KEY `ip_netid` (`ip`,`netid`,`dt`)
```

and

```
  `netid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `host` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  KEY `cc_search` (`cc`,`dt`),
  KEY `ip_search` (`ip`,`dt`),
  KEY `netid_search` (`netid`,`dt`),
  KEY `dt` (`dt`),
  KEY `ip_netid` (`ip`,`netid`,`dt`)
```

Only really relevant difference is one table is 'ip' int and the other is 'ip' varbinary to support IPv6.  When I query with:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT db.netid, INET6_NTOA(db.ip), db.cc, db.dt, db.host, db.appid
  FROM krbauths as db  INNER JOIN (SELECT ip FROM krbauths 
  WHERE dt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT netid) > 1)
  AS subQ ON db.ip = subQ.ip AND db.dt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

I get two very different results.  The first returns:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys         | key      | key_len | ref     | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL                  | NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | 97837 | NULL                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | db         | ref   | ip_search,dt,ip_netid | ip_netid | 18      | subQ.ip |     9 | Using where                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | krbauths   | range | ip_search,dt,ip_netid | dt       | 5       | NULL    | 97837 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

And the second returns:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys         | key         | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | db         | range | ip_search,dt,ip_netid | dt          | 5       | NULL              |    8 | Using where                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref   | <auto_key0>           | <auto_key0> | 4       | datalibrary.db.ip |    2 | Using index                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | krbauths   | range | ip_search,dt,ip_netid | dt          | 5       | NULL              |    8 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

I hoping someone can help me figure out why the first one is returning so many more rows (which of course takes exponentially longer to complete) than the first query on what is essentially the same data and table setup.

Also, I suck at indexing so any constructive criticism on that front would not go amiss if anyone wants to bother.

EDIT: to answer the below question without non-formatted text vomit.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ip FROM krbauths WHERE dt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT netid) > 1;
```

Results:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys         | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | krbauths | range | ip_search,dt,ip_netid | dt   | 5       | NULL | 105649 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys         | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | krbauths | range | ip_search,dt,ip_netid | dt   | 5       | NULL |    8 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And for reference, here is a the counts for the respective tables.  Number difference is accounted for by time it took to switch tables:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) from krbauths WHERE dt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    41679 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> use auths;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SELECT count(*) from krbauths WHERE dt >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    41711 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Can you compare running only the subquery? Looks like it's the only relevant part.

Comment: Put results in edit in my original post.

Comment: What is your server version?

Comment: Server version 5.6.33